# Callback for Three JS traverse

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to call a function when `Object3D`'s `traverse` is finished? (Not the callback that I add for `traverse`)

Comment: show us your code so far. Why can't you do `traverse(); callback();`. Does your traverse() do asynchronous stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call your function after the traverse:

```
object.traverse( function() {
  // my callback
});

we_are_done_traversing();
```

There is nothing asynchronuous about `.traverse()`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r69/src/core/Object3D.js#L504

Comment: Sorry, I had the `traverse` in an asynchronous `load`'s callback (for loading Collada file) and that was the problem.

Comment: It the code inside the traverse uses async, how can you make the we_are_done_traversing wait until the async code finishes?